# sqlite datastore and index.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm migrating from the original file- based datastore to the sqlite version.

I have a command line script which initialises the stub as follows:

```
from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map
from google.appengine.datastore.datastore_sqlite_stub import DatastoreSqliteStub

apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy=apiproxy_stub_map.APIProxyStubMap()
apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.RegisterStub("datastore_v3", DatastoreSqliteStub("myapp", Datastore, "/"))
```

Querying the datastore raises NeedIndexError; however -

- the relevant index definitions are staring me in the face in index.yaml
- there was no problem accessing the old file- based datastore [using DatastoreFileStub]

Am I somehow failing to initialise the datastore with index.yaml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor arguments `DatastoreSqliteStub` takes are:

```
           app_id,
           datastore_file,
           require_indexes=False,
           verbose=False,
           service_name='datastore_v3',
           trusted=False,
           consistency_policy=None
```

By providing those named arguments, you're specifying the app ID (correctly), the datastore file, which you've specified is some object called `Datastore`, and whether or not to require indexes (which you've set to '/', which evaluates to True). Instead, just specify the first and third arguments.

Comment: Super - thanks - RTFM I guess. I just copied the args from DatastoreFileStub without thinking. AppEngine rocks BTW, particularly the task queues - keep up the good work!